# Volume of A Solid in 3-space consisting of all points (x,y,z) satisfying the Inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Going through serge langs basic math, the section on Area and Applications.
I've understood that to find the area of an ellipse of the equation

$\frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{y^2}{3}$ = 1

requires one to realize that

6 and 3 are a and b respectively = $\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{3}$

however what about the case involving three dimensional space.

$\frac{x^2}{5} + \frac{y^2}{3} + \frac{z^2}{10}$

since there are three dimensions would it be correct to assume that $r^3$ is actually

$\sqrt{5} * \sqrt{3} * \sqrt{10}$

to get π$\sqrt{5} * \sqrt{3} * \sqrt{10}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this as pre-calc, I will answer that level. A circle is a special case of an ellipse (a = b = r). The area formula as a result will be

$$A = \pi \times r^2$$

The formula for the circle centered around the point (h, k) is just a special case of the formula for what you have above, with a = b = r

$$ \frac{(x-h)^2}{r^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{r^2} = 1$$

We can extend that same logic to the 3-D case. In this case

- circle --> sphere
- ellipse --> ellipsoid

The volume of a sphere is just

$$ A = \frac{4}{3}\pi \times r^3$$

You correctly identified that a = b = c = r, so you now have everything you need to derive the formula for the volume of an ellipsoid.

Comment: you knew that but did you know that we're both black guys named Adrian interested in math? >:)

Comment: What are the odds? (random person in the future - don't answer this)